# Alot of UI problems after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: lts

I have upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04 LTS, running as Virtualbox guest. The UI suffers by many response problems, mouse is moving the cursor but clicks are detected only on the left taskbar, also some applications don't seem to start.

Is there a way to fix things or at least roll back to last working version?

Comment: No, there is no "rolling back" (but you should have backed up your VM before release upgrading, that would have been your "roll back").

Comment: Ubuntu products using the *year* format (22) are different to the far more widely used *year.month* products (ie. 22 & 22.04 are different products), but if using a desktop system (ie. 22.04 and not 22) you can re-install the older version but it's not intended for server products/apps (inc. 22 & 22.04; but restoring backups as still the recommended way. Key is don't format disks, just re-use. Most upgrade instructions remind you to backup before the *release-upgrade*.

Comment: Yes, you can reload your latest snapshot in Virtualbox, from before you upgraded.